# Logic issue syncronizing flip of gameobjects child through Photon

Tags: unity-game-engine, photon

In my project I am creating a "Madness combat"-like game but multiplayer through Photon network. I am currently having a issue were the wrong clients "hand + gun" is flipped.

When client 1 flips his character his hand is flipped locally and client 2's hand is flipped locally.

Pictures: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m9B1V.jpg

I beleve the issue is the following:
In my flip logic of the character I call for a PunRPC that flips the wrong clients hand.

Main character flip function:

```
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
    if (!disableMove)
    {

        //if (!devTesting)
        //{

        if (photonView.isMine)
        {
            isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, checkRadius, whatIsGround);
            moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * speed, rb.velocity.y);

            if (facingRight == false && moveInput > 0)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Flip", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
                photonView.RPC("Fliphand", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered); //FLIPS HAND+GUN
                //Flip();
            }
            else if (facingRight == true && moveInput < 0)
            {
                photonView.RPC("Flip", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered);
                photonView.RPC("Fliphand", PhotonTargets.AllBuffered); //FLIPS HAND+GUN
                //Flip();
            }

        }
        }
```

The above function calls for this two PunRPC functions.

Character flip:

```
    [PunRPC]
void Flip()
{
        facingRight = !facingRight;     //toggle flipping
        GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = !facingRight;
}
```

Hand flip (child of above gameobject):

```
    [PunRPC]
void Fliphand()
{
        child = GameObject.Find("Hand");
        sight = GameObject.Find("Granny_warr_lasersight");
        deagle = GameObject.Find("deagle_animation");

        facingRight2 = !facingRight2;
        child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
        sight.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
        deagle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
}
```

I think the issue is since two clients join the room and  both clients have child objects called "Hand" etc. And by calling this PunRPC from client 1 it flips the "Hand" on client 2's screen.

Can anyone help me sort this issue out? I will try make it more clear if needed and provide more pictures if requested.

NOTE: Character flip works fine on both clients.

Comment: is the problem only with hand/gun? if so the issue is you are using GameObject.Find() which is static and looks for ANY object with this name. you need to specify you are looking for a child of this.gameObject. See: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Find.html

Comment: Hmm, I will check it out. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify the gun is a child of the hand, and the hand is a child of the player. Now the hand flip works! Thank you, the problem now is the gun which is a child of the hand. I dont quite get the code in your provided example..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it thanks to the link provided by Tomer Shahar!

```
    [PunRPC]
void Fliphand()
{
    //if (photonView.isMine)
    //{
    //child = GameObject.Find("Hand");
    //sight = GameObject.Find("Granny_warr_lasersight");
    //deagle = GameObject.Find("deagle_animation");

    child = player.transform.Find("Hand").gameObject;
    sight = child.transform.Find("Granny_warr_lasersight").gameObject;
    deagle = child.transform.Find("deagle_animation").gameObject;

    facingRight2 = !facingRight2;
        child.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
        sight.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
        deagle.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipY = !facingRight2;
    //}
}
```

The //disabled code is the old code that didnt work for my aplication. The new one works like a charm!